# Sharing existing ubuntu folder on host guest with Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am familiar with sharing directory between Ubuntu guest machine to host machine. But now I need to shared an existing ubuntu folder with the guest machine.

I don't understand if and how it can be done.

Does anyone have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it cannot be done in the same way in which you share a host's folder.

However, Ubuntu has SAMBA. Thus, if your guest machine Ubuntu is on any  network with the host, you can use it to share and swap files and directories between the two. Just set up Samba, and share any directory.